# How to test correct return String in Try construct after exception was thrown?

Tags: scala, tdd, scalatest

I want to test if there was an `IOException` thrown and if the correct `String` value of "[ ]" is returned. I'm only able to check the exception message and other stuff but I cannot assert the "[ ]"

```
def readJsonFile(myJson: String): String =
  Try {
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(myJson)
  } match {
    case Success(path) => new String(Files.readAllBytes(path))
    case Failure(ioe: IOException) => "[]"
    case Failure(e) => sys.error(s"There was a problem with: $e")
  }
```

I checked `assertThrows[IOException]` and `intercept[IOException]` but they only let me check for common exception stuff but not for the return value in case this kind of exception was thrown. Am I overlooking something?

What's the easiest way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `IOException` is thrown outside of `Try`. If you read the file inside `Try`, it may satisfy your expectation:

```
def readJsonFile(myJson: String): String =
  Try {
    Files.readAllBytes(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(myJson))
  } match {
    case Success(bytes) => new String(bytes)
    case Failure(ioe: IOException) => "[]"
    case Failure(e) => sys.error(s"There was a problem with: $e")
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. Thank you! BTW, any idea how I can test the last `case Failure(e) => sys.error(s"There was a problem with: $e")`?

Comment: I don't think you can test an unexpected exception. If you have a scenario, you can use scalatest intercept feature. It's for cases that you expect an exception. If no exception is thrown, then test fails. This blog post explains it very clearly: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scalatest-testing-expected-exceptions-intercept-testfailedexception

Comment: ([`new String(bytes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) might also throw an exception (it is not specified what might happen). It is preferred to use the known `Charset` and handle the failures.)